# PHPunit: Form Ancestor Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a simple form:

```
      <!--NEW FORM-->
<form method="POST" action="http://192.168.114.139/family/search_results" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="admin-form"><input
        name="_token" type="hidden" value="7v2IhbTkiMRVyojJ8Vuv0dDdRqySzO18Z6gPWKP2">

    <input class="gui-input" id="search_term" placeholder="" name="search_term" type="text">

    <div class="panel-footer text-right">
        <input class="button btn-primary" name="submit" id="search" type="submit" value="Search">
        <button class="button btn-danger" type="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to test this form using Laravel's Laracasts\Integrated package.
I have the following test method written:

```
/** @test */
public function it_can_search()
{
    $this->login()
        ->visit('/identification/search_family/')
        ->see('Search Families')
        ->submitForm('Search',['search_term' => 'tests'])
        ->seePageIs('/identification/search_family/');
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

There was 1 error:

```
1) ExampleTest::it_can_seach
LogicException: The selected node does not have a form ancestor.

/var/www/html/srs/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Form.php:400
/var/www/html/srs/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Link.php:55
/var/www/html/srs/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Form.php:49
/var/www/html/srs/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Crawler.php:770
/var/www/html/srs/vendor/laracasts/integrated/src/Extensions/IntegrationTrait.php:397
/var/www/html/srs/vendor/laracasts/integrated/src/Extensions/IntegrationTrait.php:380
/var/www/html/srs/vendor/laracasts/integrated/src/Extensions/Traits/LaravelTestCase.php:47
/var/www/html/srs/tests/ExampleTest.php:23

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 8, Errors: 1.
```

I know the error means the Dom-crawler can't find the form associated with the input, but I don't understand why... Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The selected node does not have a form ancestor - Mink error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401236/the-selected-node-does-not-have-a-form-ancestor-mink-error)

Comment: @limonte I've seen that post you are referring to. The solution the responder gave was to ensure the elements are within the `<form>...</form>`. Mine meet that criteria.

Comment: It may be a simple thing, but I can't see links between the `see()` or `submitForm()` methods and the form itself. None of the strings appear - "Visa type", "Add Type" aren't in the form.

Comment: @M1ke The test visits the page with the form on it, then `->see('Search Families')` That one is just confirming that it is on the right page. `->submitForm('Search',['search_term' => 'tests'])` The submitForm method asks for the name of the button, and then it asks how to fill out the form. In my case, I'm saying to input `tests` into the `search_term` field.

Comment: @M1ke, Oh, I see what your saying. I copied the wrong test method into the post. Sorry about that. I edited my post.